# How to draw custom labels by factors to a ggnet plot?

Tags: r, ggnet2

The following code

```
ggnet2(net, mode = "fruchtermanreingold",
       color = "module", palette = y, alpha = 0.75, size = 1, edge.alpha = 0.3,
       edge.color = c("color", "grey50"),
       set.seed(123))
```

returns this plot

[image]

Since the complexity of the network is high I want to draw unique labels on the plot, which means adding the module's name over the cluster of points that belong to the module. Hence, identifying each module will be easier.

I've tried with the label argument in various ways without getting the result

```
ggnet2(net, mode = "fruchtermanreingold",
       color = "module", palette = y, alpha = 0.75, size = 1, edge.alpha = 0.3,
       edge.color = c("color", "grey50"), **label = "module"**,
       set.seed(123))

modColor <- unique(geneME$moduleColor) #geneME is the data frame in which the gene-to-module relation is stored

ggnet2(net, mode = "fruchtermanreingold",
       color = "module", palette = y, alpha = 0.75, size = 1, edge.alpha = 0.3,
       edge.color = c("color", "grey50"), label = modColor,
       set.seed(123))
```

The net is directed with 9000 vertices and 1.5M edges

Answer (score 1):

This network came from a weighted gene coexpression network analysis (WGCNA). To solve this issue through a sort of hand-made recipe do the following steps.

-First, obtain intra-modular connectivity for each module by using the

```
intramodularConnectivity.fromExpr(...., getWholeNetworkConnectivity = TRUE)
```

function of WGCNA R package.

-Then filter the most within-module-connected gene (highest **kWithin**) for each module (**maxGeneConnectME**), (a df with two columns, one is the module, and the other the gene id)

-Obtain modules names

```
modsNet <- net %v% "module" %>% unique
```

-After that obtain "module-numbers" lists where in each list only the maxGene will be labeled,the rest genes will be NAs

```
ls <- lapply(modsNet, function(x){

maxGene <- maxGeneConnectME[maxGeneConectME$module == x,]$geneid


modsNet2 <- net %v% "module"

# assign NA to the nodes in which are not **maxGene**
modsNet2[which(network.vertex.names(net) != maxGene)] <- NA


return(modsNet2)})
```

-Generate a vector with the same length of total nodes of the net, and then assign NA to the nodes that not represent all the maxGenes and assign the name of the module to the nodes which correspond to maxGene

```
vec <- numeric(length = *nodes.number.of.net*)
for(i in 1:length(ls)){
  
  # obtain maxGene position in each list
  numb <- which(!is.na(ls[[i]]))
  # replace numb-position of vec with the name of the module
  # where the gene belongs
  vec[numb] <- ls[[i]][numb]
  
}

vec[vec == "0"] <- NA
```

-This will allow us to label only the maxGenes with the name of the module

```
ggnet2(net, mode = "fruchtermanreingold",
       color = "module", palette = y, alpha = 0.75, size = 1, edge.alpha = 0.3,
       edge.color = c("color", "grey50"), label = vec,
       set.seed(123))
```

producing something like this

[image]

Comment: fantastic answer I was looking for something like this im trying to follow this to generate the network i would like to know what this `net` object its is it what is inside the object? you have turned into graph object but what does it contain if you can show me the how did you get `net` it would be really helpful

Comment: net is a network object created with the network function of the homonymous package (network) and comes from a data frame with two columns indicating the source and target connection of nodes.

In this case, the data frame looks like one column is tagged 'Source' and the other 'Target', and for example, the first row is (geneID1, geneID2), the second one (geneID1, geneID3), (geneID2, geneID8) and so on. I avoided repeated connections like (geneID2, geneID1). They don't contribute.

The net object has edges and nodes, please refer to the network vignette to understand how to work with it.